# Merge ListViews Android

Tags: android, listview

Na minha aplicação, tenho dois Fragments, um pra carregar Tweets e outro para Ler um RSS.
RSS

```
public class RssFragment extends ListFragment {

    private RssListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            List<JSONObject> jobs = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
            try {
                jobs = RssReader.getLatestRssFeed();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Error loading RSS Feed Stream >> " + e.getMessage() + " //" + e.toString());
            }

            adapter = new RssListAdapter(getActivity(),jobs);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);    

    }

Tweets
public class Noticias extends ListFragment {
    final static String twitterScreenName = "";
    final static String TWITTER_API_KEY = "";
    final static String TWITTER_API_SECRET = "";
    private static final String TAG = "Tweet";


    @Override  
      public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {  
       //new CustomToast(getActivity(), numbers_digits[(int) id]);     
      }  

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .permitNetwork()
        .build());

            ArrayList<TwitterTweet> twitterTweets = null;
            TwitterAPI twitterAPI = new TwitterAPI(TWITTER_API_KEY,TWITTER_API_SECRET);
            twitterTweets = twitterAPI.getTwitterTweets("LinkOffTMMG");

            ArrayAdapter<TwitterTweet> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<TwitterTweet>(  
                inflater.getContext(), R.layout.twitter_tweets_list,  
                R.id.listTextView, twitterTweets);  

            setListAdapter(adapter);  

            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);    

    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para criar outro Fragment juntanto o conteudo dos outros dois ordenado pela data mais recente?

Comment: A minha sugestão seria criar um `Adapter` customizado (subclasse de BaseAdapter) com acesso a esses dois *DataSet's* pra exibir os dois.

Comment: Mas como faço para receber mais de um tipo em um BaseAdapter?

Comment: Acredito que você terá que criar uma classe que implemente a lógica de *merge*. Implementando os métodos abstratos da classe `BaseAdapter´.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa programar baseando-se em Interfaces.

Resumindo, crie uma interface que contenha dois métodos, um para pegar a foto da notícia e outro para pegar o título da notícia. 
Após isso, crie uma adapter customizado que herde de BaseAdapter e receba uma lista dessa interface. Pronto! :-)

```
public interface Noticia {
   Bitmap getFoto();
   String getTitulo();
}

public class NoticiaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   private List<Noticia> mNoticias;

   public NoticiaAdapter(Context context, List<Noticia> noticias) {
      this.mNoticias = noticias;
   }

   getCount(...) { ... }
   getItem(...) { ... }
   getItemId(...) { ... }
   getView(...) { ... }

}
```

Comment: A idéia é boa, mas faltou um _getter_ ou campo para a data, o OP quer a lista ordenada por notícia mais recente. Talvez seja o caso de `Noticia` ser uma classe abstrata e não uma interface.